# Feedparser Python Error : KeyError : 'title'

Tags: python, python-2.7, feedparser

I have seen a lot of KeyCount Errors online but none of them quite match the troubles that I'm having. I am using feed parser to try and create a one run application that accesses all the URLs in a text file and outputs all the entries in each URL. When I run this code :

```
     import feedparser as f

     with open('addresses.rtf', 'r') as addresses:
         for line in addresses:
             d = f.parse(line)

            print d["feed"]["title"]
             print ""
             print d.feed.subtitle
             print ""

             for post in d.entries:
                 print post.title
                 print post.link
                 print ""
```

I get this error message :

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/Users/Josh/Desktop/Feed Parser Python Project/init.py", line 7, in <module>
print d["feed"]["title"]
       File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/feedparser.py", line 375, in __getitem__
return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
     KeyError: 'title'
```

My text file is just a .rtf file that has a URL on each line (3 lines).

If someone could give us a hand please let me know and if you need any extra info please don't hesitate to ask. Any help is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: You will need to convert your 'Rich Text Format' [rtf] document into plain text before you open it. Or else find some library that can handle RTF.

Comment: copy paste some line here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what is wrong here, but in the general case, any `KeyError` is because the data you are trying to access is not exactly what you expected. It's best to throw your assumptions out the window and take a close look at the actual data that your code is working with.

For debugging, I would recommend taking a close look at what happens before the error. What is the value of `line` as you read the file? Is it correct? What is the value of `d`? Did the call to `f.parse(line)` result in a valid object?